# Soft wdt reset error on NodeMCU (ESP8266)

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-due

I am getting error on Serial monitor Soft WDT reset. I decoded the error code also and found the following stacktrace.

I am using SIM808 module and DFRobot_sim808 as the library.

> 0x4010030d: millis at AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring.c line 180
>
> 0x401003b9: __digitalWrite at AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_digital.c line 82
>
> 0x40202863: sim808_wait_for_resp(char const*, DataType, unsigned int, unsigned int) at Documents\Arduino\libraries\DFRobot_SIM808-master/sim808.cpp line 172
>
> 0x402027a4: sim808_send_byte(unsigned char) at Documents\Arduino\libraries\DFRobot_SIM808-master/sim808.cpp line 118
>
> 0x402028ce: sim808_check_with_cmd(char const*, char const*, DataType, unsigned int, unsigned int) at Documents\Arduino\libraries\DFRobot_SIM808-master/sim808.cpp line 191
>
> 0x402025dc: DFRobot_SIM808::init() at Documents\Arduino\libraries\DFRobot_SIM808-master/DFRobot_sim808.cpp line 63
>
> 0x402024c1: setup at G:\Development\ESP8266\SIM Module\sim_module/sim_module.ino line 41 (discriminator 1)
>
> 0x40203248: loop_wrapper() at AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp line 122
>
> 0x40100e8d: cont_wrapper at AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266/cont.S line 81

I tried to find solution for the same everywhere but none found it. But the same code I am trying on arduino it works but not for ESP8266. I dont have long waiting loop(). But still it gives me error.

Below is the code for the same

```
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define PHONE_NUMBER "********"  

#define MESSAGE  "hello,world"

#define PIN_TX D1 
#define PIN_RX D0

SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_RX, PIN_TX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
  }
  while(!sim808.init()) {
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("Sim808 init error\r\n");
  } 
  Serial.println("Sim808 init success");
  Serial.println("Start to send message ...");

  sim808.sendSMS(PHONE_NUMBER,MESSAGE);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culpret is the SIM808 library. It's not written to work well with the ESP8266.

The problem lies in [this function](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_SIM808/blob/master/sim808.cpp#L158):

```
boolean sim808_wait_for_resp(const char* resp, DataType type, unsigned int timeout, unsigned int chartimeout)
{
    int len = strlen(resp);
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned long timerStart, prevChar;    //prevChar is the time when the previous Char has been read.
    timerStart = millis();
    prevChar = 0;
    while(1) {
        if(sim808_check_readable()) {
            char c = serialSIM808->read();
            prevChar = millis();
            sum = (c==resp[sum]) ? sum+1 : 0;
            if(sum == len)break;
        }
        if ((unsigned long) (millis() - timerStart) > timeout * 1000UL) {
            return false;
        }
        //If interchar Timeout => return FALSE. So we can return sooner from this function.
        if (((unsigned long) (millis() - prevChar) > chartimeout) && (prevChar != 0)) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    //If is a CMD, we will finish to read buffer.
    if(type == CMD) sim808_flush_serial();
    return true;
}
```

It has a loop that can take some time to run, and it doesn't `yield()` at any point to allow the ESP8266's housekeeping routines to run and "kick the dog".

Adding a call to `yield()` inside the `while(1)` loop should cure the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Really appreciated. But I am facing I more issue after 10-12 "Sim808 init error" I receive success why is it so why it does not get initialised in first attempt.

Comment: Probably waiting to connect to the network. That can take up to a minute sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nothing to bother. There was some contact issue between Gnd Pins of both modules.